# DIV под наклоном

Tags: css, html

Помогите, пожалуйста. Мне нужно сделать:

1. Дивы неправильной формы
2. Чтобы при наведении на див менялся бэкграунд

Пока что у меня получается только накладывать прямоугольные блоки с фоном, но в этом случае они залезают друг на друга и при наведении меняется только часть фона. Может вы сможете подсказать как это лучше реализовать?

Заранее спасибо

**HTML**

```
<div class="serv_block">
        <div class="serv_block1"></div>
        <div class="serv_block2"></div> 
        <div class="serv_block3"></div>
        <div class="serv_block4"></div>
    </div>`
```

**CSS**

```
.serv_block1 {
    background: url(../img/serv_block1.png) no-repeat top left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;   
    float: left;
     -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%,100% 0,50% 100%,0 100%); 
    margin-left: -9%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    shape-outside: url(../img/serv_block1.png);
}
.serv_block4:hover {
    background: url(../img/serv_block44.png) no-repeat top right;

}
.serv_block2 {
    background: url(../img/serv_block2.png) no-repeat top right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;   
    float: right;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%,100% 0,100% 100%,0% 100%);
    margin-right: -6%; 
    margin-top: -650px;
    shape-outside: url(../img/serv_block2.png);
}
.serv_block3 {
    background: url(../img/serv_block3.png) no-repeat top left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;   
    float: left; 
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%,100% 0,50% 100%,0 100%);

    margin-left: -9%;
    shape-outside: url(../img/serv_block3.png);
}
.serv_block4 {
    background: url(../img/serv_block4.png) no-repeat top right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative; 
    float: right;
     overflow:hidden;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0%,100% 0,100% 100%,0% 100%);
    margin-right: -6%;
    margin-top: -650px;
    shape-outside: url(../img/serv_block4.png);
}
```

[image: Блоки]

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, функциональную часть Вашего кода к вопросу

Comment: Добавил код который сейчас

Comment: Я уже поправил, но пожалуйста, на будущее, пользуйтесь тегами "Код" и иже с ними.

Comment: спасибо, буду внимательнее

Comment: ох дизайнеры как понавыдумывают :?(

Comment: Чтобы при наведении на див менялся бекграунд - это псевокласс :hover , а неправильной формы - это как? ромбом? Так тут поможет transform

Comment: ну видите там у блока на картинке одна сторона скошена - как сместить именно блок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, неплохое решение сделать два вложенных блока. Внешний задает форму с одной скошенной стороной:

```
transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
transform-origin: 0% 50%;
overflow: hidden;
```

А внутренний с фоном подвергается обратной трансформации, чтобы картинка на фоне не искажалась.

```
 background-image: url('...');
 transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(30deg);
 transform-origin: 0% 0%;
```